# How Can I Set The Cookie Expire Every 30 Seconds

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if how can I set the cookie of a modal pop-up to expire every 1 minute.

Here's the code I have:

```js
var MineKwait = "Mon, 07 Dec 2017 01:51:00 UTC"

if (getCookie("underme")) {
  $("#book-cover")
    .remove()
}
focus()
var listener = addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (document.activeElement === document.getElementById('book-frame')) {
    // clicked
    document.cookie = "underme=true; expires=" + MineKwait;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#book-cover").remove();
    }, 500);

  }
})
```

Comment: Why mixing pure JS with jQuery this way ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki what alternative can you suggest?

Comment: Use one of them.

Comment: As a piece of advice: When posting a question and using an inline-snippet, there's a `Tidy` button on the left-hand side. Please make sure to make use of this next time - it makes your code much easier to read, which in turn can help you get more answers!

Comment: I'm confused. How to fix it? @ZakariaAcharki